# target server failed to response spark s3

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark, invocationtargetexception

I have a spark offline job sitting in Amazon EC2 reading out of s3 and dumping the output back in s3. More often than never the job runs successfully but sometimes it fails with

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:251)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:223)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:682)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRequest(RestStorageService.java:326)
at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRequest(RestStorageService.java:277)
at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRestPut(RestStorageService.java:1143)
at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.copyObjectImpl(RestStorageService.java:2117)
at org.jets3t.service.StorageService.copyObject(StorageService.java:898)
at org.jets3t.service.StorageService.copyObject(StorageService.java:943)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.copy(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:320)
```

The issue seems to be with jets3t writing the output back to s3. I have around 100gb of input which get processed and generated around 600mb of output.